# Why do I get keep getting this tzinfo error?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, timezone

I'm almost a complete beginner in Python. I'm trying to plot some dates on the X axis and I keep getting a tzinfo error. The error seems to be in the final line shown, as when I comment it out it doesn't occur.

```
mydates = pd.date_range('2021-01-10', '2021-02-15').tolist()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(date_data[::-1], cum_dose1[::-1])
ax.plot(mydates, (15*10**6)*np.ones(len(mydates)))
```

The error I get is: `TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'UnitData'` - I'm not sure why I keep getting it! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `tzinfo` specifies a time zone for a datetime object. it should be `None` for the datetime objects of a pd.date_range. which version of pandas / matplotlib are you using? I have no issues running your code with matplotlib 3.3.3 and pandas 1.2.0