# how to fix this type erro of tzinfo argument? TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'UnitData'

Tags: python

when i use plt to draw the plots(more the one in the same pic), then given a bug:
TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'UnitData'

how to fix this bug? thanks

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.style as psl
import datetime
import os
os.chdir(r'D:\Code\python code')

from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import pmdarima as pm

date_parse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y/%m/%d')
df = pd.read_table('ch4_time_series.txt', sep=',', index_col='Date', date_parser=date_parse)
print(df.head())
print(df.shape)

train_df = df.iloc[:125]
test_df = df.iloc[125:]

model = pm.auto_arima(train_df.Orders, start_p=1, d=None, start_q=1,
                      information_criterion='aic',
                      test='adf', # 
                      max_p=3, max_q=3,
                      # max_d=2, 
                      m=1,
                      seasonal=False,
                      start_P=0,
                      D=0,
                      trace=True,
                      error_action='ignore',
                      suppress_warnings=True,
                      stepwise=True)
print(model.summary())

n_periods = 10 # The number of periods in the future to forecast.
fc, confit = model.predict(n_periods=n_periods,
                           return_conf_int = True 
                           )
index_of_fc = pd.date_range(max(train_df.index), periods = n_periods)
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=index_of_fc)
lower = pd.Series(confit[:, 0], index=index_of_fc)
upper = pd.Series(confit[:, 1], index=index_of_fc)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
psl.use('seaborn-dark')
plt.plot(train_df.Orders, ls='-', label='True_train_df')
plt.plot(fc_series, color='darkgreen')
plt.fill_between(index_of_fc,
                  lower,
                  upper,
                  color='k',
                  alpha=0.15)
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.legend(loc=1)
```

The error I get is: `TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'UnitData'`

and the version info as follow:
numpy version: 1.21.5
pandas version: 1.4.2
matplotlib version: 3.5.1

**this is the Traceback:**

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1914b1a44c0>]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 455, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 436, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 73, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2810, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3082, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1158, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1045, in _update_ticks
    major_locs = self.get_majorticklocs()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1277, in get_majorticklocs
    return self.major.locator()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1340, in __call__
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1125, in viewlim_to_dt
    return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 528, in num2date
    return _from_ordinalf_np_vectorized(x, tz).tolist()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2163, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2246, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 359, in _from_ordinalf
    dt = dt.astimezone(tz)
TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'UnitData'
```

Comment: There's no `tzinfo` anywhere in your code. Please add the full traceback so we can see where this is happening.

Comment: @Barmar I've added the traceback, thanks so much!

Comment: This seems to be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466481/trying-to-connect-scatter-plotted-datetimes-gives-me-tz-error-from-matplot

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753940/why-do-i-get-keep-getting-this-tzinfo-error The common factor seems to be trying to plot a date range.

Comment: Thanks so much! @Barmar This loop for date is the answer! from this link that you sent to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466481/trying-to-connect-scatter-plotted-datetimes-gives-me-tz-error-from-matplot

the new code:
date_parse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y/%m/%d')
df = pd.read_table('ch4_time_series.txt', sep=',', date_parser=date_parse) # index_col='Date', 
df['Date'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y/%m/%d').date() for dates in df['Date']]

Comment: Please do not add "answers" to the question body. Instead, add them as a separate answer, see [answer]. Given the question is closed as a duplicate, you can add the answer there (provided it is unique and adds something to the question of course)